# Ranking based on 2 measures

Tags: ranking

Please help me what method should I used to find the best performing schools as some schools have nearly 1000 students attended exam where as for some schools nearly 100 students attended. How can I say that the 120 student school performing best. I think I need to consider 2 measures students attended and passed and then find a way to rank the best ones
[image]

Comment: Beware a simple ranking due to the varying school sizes you are looking at! Statistically the highest and lowest performing schools are both more likely to be small, because variation is a tricky beast: https://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2010/09/the-small-schools-myth.html

Comment: You need more data. It goes without saying that the exam must be the same (or comparable) for all schools, but what is also important are the marks; for example at one school 100% of the students passed with 70% (barely passed) while at another school 90% of the students passed (and only 10% received a mark of less than 85%). You can see that even amongst great schools the actual grade awarded can vary, and it matters how many get how much: https://i.stack.imgur.com/diKlN.png

Comment: Did all students attend the exams? If not, are there differences in attendance? (In some places, Oslo is one, it is reported that schools *ask* their weaker students to be *sick* the day of the exam)